# How to have images in line with text in css

Tags: html, css, image, text, footer

I'm creating the footer of my website using html and css.

I want to have the two facebook and twitter images in line with the text so that everything in the footer is in line with eachother

At the moment my footer code is

HTML -

```
<div class="footer content">

        <img src="Images/facebook.png">
        <img src="Images/twitter.png">

        <p> Address line 1
                        Address line 2
                        Address line 3

  </p>

</div> <!--end of footer-->
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`<p>` tags are block-level elements. Use an inline element such as `<span>`:

```html
<div class="footer content">
    <img src="Images/facebook.png" />
    <img src="Images/twitter.png">
    <span> 
        Address line 1
        Address line 2
        Address line 3
    </span>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you're able to use CSS, you can define both elements as `inline-block`:

```css
.footer.content > img,
.footer.content > p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Example 1 jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDRja/1/)

[**Example 2 jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDRja/)

**EDIT:** It might also be wise for semantics to use `<address>`, rather than `<span>`. For example:

```html
<div class="footer content">
    <img src="Images/facebook.png" />
    <img src="Images/twitter.png">
    <address> 
        Address line 1
        Address line 2
        Address line 3
    </address>
</div>
```

Since `<address>` is also a block-level element, you'll need to include the correct CSS as follows:

```css
.footer.content > img,
.footer.content > address {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Final jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LBYy/)

Comment: If we are in the debate of semantic you are wrong too, now the new nav tag resolve the debate.

http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Comment: It doesn't, not really. `<nav>` should be used for navigation. This isn't navigation is it, it's two images and an address. I've updated the answer to be more semantic.

Comment: Without links attached to them, yes.

Comment: You forgot the footer tag

Comment: I left out `footer` because I didn't want to over-complicate the issue by mentioning the caveat of using a shiv / shim.

Answer (score 1):

`.content img, .content p {
float:left
}`
float: left/right - depending where you want it to be

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `<span>` instead of `<p>`. `<p>` makes a new paragraph which is quit "independent".

Comment: Why not upvote the answer that better explains the difference between `<p>` and `<span>`?

Comment: Because life is flowing in background and don't wait till you do something? When I started writing answer no answer was written to. Simple. Don't worry you will get your points BenM.

Comment: Why do you arguing? BenM. Are you sitting next to me to now what was happening in my Bubble? Please stop this empty discussion.

Comment: It is not THE FACT this is only your speculation. O.K. can be your opinion. Also word "better" is relative so as a fact you should use words "THE BEST".

Answer (score 1):

Check out this working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BalaVaradarajan/7TV6D/1).

```
.channels li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.625em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use new tags specific for footer and address this is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4b4pU/1/):

```
<footer id="footer">

    <span><img src="Images/facebook.png" alt="some text" /></span>
        <span> <img src="Images/twitter.png" alt="some text"/></span>
                <span>
                    <address>
                        Address line 1
                        Address line 2
                    Address line 3
                    </address>    
            </span>
</footer>


#footer {display:inline;}
#footer address {display:inline }
```

The alt to images was added to help with disability and standards.

Answer (score 0):

I find a lot of the time I need to adjust the position of the image to align with the text. You can do this by wrapping the text and image in a div with position relative and then assigning position absolute on the image. Then you ca add top and margin left to adjust the position relative to the text. https://jsfiddle.net/edhescqn/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="amazonLink">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="amazonLink__text">Buy Now on Amazon</div>
        <img class="amazonLink__image" 
            src="http://cdn2.iconmonstr.com/wp-content/assets/preview/2016/240/iconmonstr-amazon-1.png" width="24px" height="24px">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.amazonLink {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.amazonLink__text {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.amazonLink__image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **display:inline-block** css property for image ad text to display image and text in same line